# Calling a subclass variable in the parent class __init__()?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

My apologies if this is a trivial question.  I am trying to pass a subclass variable as an argument in the parent class `__init__()` but get an 'undefined name' warning.

For example: The subclass (`JumpingJacks`) variable `PATH` is considered an 'undefined name' when I try to use it in the parent class (`Exercise`) instantiation.

```
class JumpingJacks(Exercise):
    """Creates JumpingJack instance, an Exercise with default attributes
    common to the Exercise (parent) and unique to JumpingJacks:

    Exercise(name, reps, per_side=False, path=None)
    """
    PATH = "Jumping Jacks.PNG"
    def __init__(self, reps, name="Jumping Jacks"):
        Exercise.__init__(self, 
                          name, reps, 
                          per_side=False, 
                          path=PATH)
```

I suspect the answer relates to class inheritance, but because `PATH` is local during the parent class `__init__()`, I don't understand why `PATH` is undefined.  I have been unable to find a succinct explanation.  What part of this am I misunderstanding or doing incorrectly?

I realize I could hard-code the path into the parent class `__init__()` like this:

```
path="Jumping Jacks.PNG"
```

Rather than:

```
path=PATH
```

But I think its better practice to use the class variable instead if all instances share the common variable.  Correct me if this way of thinking is incorrect.

How do I call the subclass variable in the parent class `__init__()`?

Comment: You need to use `self.PATH`.

Comment: Thanks!  That answers my question completely.  I am newer to SO: Should I remove the question since your comment answers it?

Comment: consider using `super` instead of `Exercise.__init__`, eg `super(JumpingJacks, self).__init__(name=name, reps=reps, per_side=False, path=self.PATH)`

Comment: @Anentropic Thanks for your input!  I am newer to super() and until I understand it more fully, I am using the explicit parent class. Perhaps Ill make that my next question("When to use super()?")...

Comment: Yes you should make a new question and no you should not remove this one @BrenBarn should make his suggestion and answer and not a comment